# Action bar show differently on android 2.2 and on android 5.0

Tags: android

In my application I had set minimum sdk version as 9 and targeted and compiled version as 21. Had Defined a theme with the same name that inherits from the material theme in res/values-v21/styles.xml.

when I run the application it looks on 2.3 as:
[image]

and on 5.0 it looks as:

[image]

In 2.3 it does not show the top right side 3 dots. Why is it so.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 2.3 there is no action bar it has menu. In 5.0 menu item is shown in 3 dot & in 2.3 it is shown in menu which is found by menu button.

Comment: then what is solution for same actionbar?

Comment: in 2.3 we make Actionbar by support library. So, it is expected that it may not same as actual ActionBar. I think you can not do it. But actionbar menu item is found in Menu bar. So what else you want to give.

Comment: actually i set the icon of that actionbar in 2.3...bt its not displaying me the icon, its displaying me title of that menu item...

Comment: check this link. It might help. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html